# is window.document.element a valid object?

Tags: javascript

Just as window and document objects in JS corresponds to  window(?) and <body> elements in HTML, can you refer to more nested elements of the <body> simply by appending with dots(.)? (like window.document.p)

I haven't seen it anywhere but I don't know since *I haven't seen it anywhere*. It just seemed intuitive to me that nested elements in HTML be represented as nested objects in JavaScript instead of having to getElementByID but somehow this chain seems broken after window.document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some nested elements can be accessed diretcly using

```
 document.
```

, e.g.,

```
 document.forms
```

, which is an array containing all forms on the page.

In general, however, you have either to traverse the dom tree using

```
 element.children or element.childNodes
```

or access the element directly using methods like

```
 document.getElementById()
 document.querySelector()
```

an alike.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible. You should just try it before you post.

You can access descendants of `<body>` by calling its `getElementsByTagName` method or the new `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` methods.

You should check this documentation for more info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element

Answer (score 1):

no, that isn't possible. but for some elements, there are special collections;

```
window.document.forms  -> all form elements
window.document.images -> all image elements
window.frames          -> all frame elements
```

Comment: for traversing the dom (finding all span elements, for instance), use jquery/zepto/dojo/mootools or a queryselector implementation such as sizzle. If you are only supporting modern Browsers, you could also use [element].querySelectorAll('selector') directly